# How to correctly cancel a task in c#?

Tags: c#, multithreading

`CancellationTokenSource` seems to be ignoring the time for the loop operation. It takes a while to iterate over it and I have the limit set to 500ms but it's ignoring it. What could I be doing wrong?

```
static async Task<int> Thread1()
{
  CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
  source.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
  return await Task.Run(async () =>
  {
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {          
      var site = await client.GetAsync("http://webcode.me", source.Token);
      for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
      }
      string content = await site.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
      return content.Count(x => x == 'e');
    }
  }, source.Token);
}
```

Comment: Cancellation is *cooperative*. If you're not checking the token, nothing is going to cause your code to stop running once it starts.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks, I thought having it passed in `Task.Run` would handle that but apparently not.

Comment: The designers of this API learnt from the mistakes of `Thread.Abort`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're never checking for cancellation in your loop.

Call the following in your loop:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken.throwifcancellationrequested?view=netframework-4.8

e.g.

```
token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
```

which is equal to:

```
if (token.IsCancellationRequested)   
    throw new OperationCanceledException(token);
```

Comment: There is no way to pass a token to [`HttpContent.ReadAsStringAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcontent.readasstringasync).

Comment: It would be ideal for you to post the code in the answer and avoid linking externally as an important part of your answer.

Comment: @Enigmativity i get that but a) its just one method b) its on msdn not some vague blog. I have adhered to your request however.